# Change token type of DefaultApplication WSO2 APIM 3.1.0

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server

When creating a new user in WSO2 APIM 3.1.0, by default, he creates an application called DefaultApplication. How do I change this DefaultApplication to be created as OAUTH instead of JWT?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2GrD.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can create another new application by selecting the Token Type as JWT. If you really want an application with the name of `DefaultApplication` then delete that app and create a new app with the name `DefaultApplication`. For more information on creating applications refer [1]

[1] https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.1.0/learn/consume-api/manage-application/create-application/#create-applications

Comment: I would like this DefaultApplication application to come as standard with OAUTH already.

This DEVPORTAL will be available to external developers and I would not like to ask that he have to change this option JWT